# Bit.ly share textbox functionality

Tags: javascript, bit.ly

Does anyone have a clue to how bit.ly is replacing the textarea as soon as you finish typing the link?

Comment: What do you mean? It isn't replaced, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the OP is asking how bit.ly converts the long URL into a shorter URL without reloading the page.  This would be done with an AJAX call to a web page, that has a script running on it.

Here is my attempt getting a similar effect on a form submit, I don't know what aspect is what you are most interested in.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('formElement').onsubmit = "return requestURL();";
function requestURL() {
    var data = document.getElementById('formInputData').value; // get value from <input type="text" id="formInputData />
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var request=new XMLHttpRequest(); // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    }
    else {
        var request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // code for IE6, IE5
    }
    request.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        // if the request worked, output the data the server returned (PHP, .net, etc.)
        document.getElementById('serveroutput').innerHTML = result.responseText;
    }
    request.open("GET", "serverscript.ext?data="+data, "true"); // Setup the server request
    request.send(); // Send the request to the server
    return false; // Stops the form from submitting normally
}
</script>
```

This example has no security, style, or other special stuff, but might give a better idea.
JSON or similar methods are probably used to get data back to JavaScript, which then styles and displays the data.  I can't give specifics of what bit.ly uses, but this is the idea I would use if I tried a similar JavaScript solution.

How did I answer the question?  Did I answer something completely different?  Should I expand on the answer?  Do I ask too many questions? (Yes to the last question)

---

In response to a comment upon pressing the space bar, that functionality can be added to the above code with the following function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('formInputData').onkeypress = function() {
        if(document.getElementById('formInputData').value.split('')[-1] === " ") {
            document.getElementById('formInputData').value = document.getElementById('formInputData').value.substring(0, str.length - 1);
            requestURL();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ya that's pretty much what i was asking, like how bit.ly converts the long URL into a shorter URL as the user is typing.

Comment: Technically it's not as the user is typing, the URL is converted after the user submits the form.  If I answered your question, you can mark the question as answered so others know it has been solved.

Comment: no the way bit.ly has it is as the user finishes typing a site, it automatically changes the long url to short url (without submitting the form), i guess ur answer isn't really what I'm looking for.  

for example:  as i type "hello this is my twitter www.twitter.com/myTwitter come look at my tweets!"

as soon as i finish typing "myTwitter" and press space that long url is changed to short url.  I'm guessing bit.ly checks every word when user presses space?

Comment: Are you talking about something in Twitter?  On my computer, the bitly.com site doesn't respond to a space, I need to press the "shorten" button.  I will update my answer to show how to respond to a space.

Comment: sorry i should've clarified.  Yes what i meant was sharing your status to the social media you've added through bit.ly.  (so if you had added facebook and twitter, you can post through bit.ly).  So when you write out your message it automatically converts your long url to short url.

Comment: OK, well my question only answers assuming you are using the homepage, and I included code to check about the space in the URL.  My code could be expanded to check if the last string entered was a URL, and then replaces the URL in the textbox with the result of the AJAX call.  It's not something I'm going to be able to code quickly.

Comment: No that's good enough!  i was just asking how i should go about it.  Thanks a lot!